# path not drawn in d3 stacked area chart

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to plot a stacked area chart

I've distilled the problem down to [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dVU7NRwVsxjiQLRRKnoS).

Sample data is below and I've confirmed that the data (recalculated by the stack layout) is passed to areaFcn, the area generator function.  Just that the paths are never updated with the data.  I have no idea why.

Anyone?

Thanks!

```
var areaFcn = function(d, i) {
 d3.svg.area() 
 .x(function(d, i) { return xScaleT(d.t); }) 
 .y0(function(d) { return yScale(d.y0); }) 
 .y1(function(d) { return yScale(d.y0 + d.y); }); 
}

var inData = [ {"data":[
 {"svName":"BBC [890]","avgBW":9654498}, 
 {"svName":"CNN [453]","avgBW":4033202}, 
 {"svName":"ESPN [984]","avgBW":4715123}], 
 "timestamp":1430712151000}, 
 {"data":[ 
 {"svName":"BBC [890]","avgBW":9654498}, 
 {"svName":"CNN [453]","avgBW":4033202}, 
 {"svName":"ESPN [984]","avgBW":4715123}], 
 "timestamp":1430712153000}, 
 {"data":[ 
 {"svName":"BBC [890]","avgBW":4103549}, 
 {"svName":"CNN [453]","avgBW":4413707}, 
 {"svName":"ESPN [984]","avgBW":11648783}], 
 "timestamp":1430712156000} 
]
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/dVU7NRwVsxjiQLRRKnoS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path has no `d` attribute. Some debugging in the code shows, that the function `areaFcn` returns undefined. Change it to this and it'll work:

```
var areaFcn = d3.svg.area()
.x(function(d, i) {
    return xScaleT(d.t); })
.y0(function(d) {
    return yScale(d.y0); })
.y1(function(d) {
    return yScale(d.y0 + d.y); });
```